# IBM MQ .NET library not reading app.config

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I am using instructions in this [IBM support page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q123550_.htm) to set up tracing. No trace files are being output. I tried this on a machine that has IBM MQ client installed and on a machine with no IBM MQ client. Is there anything I can do to debug or investigate?

I am on v9.0.1 of IBM MQ.

Comment: turned out that there was an install of MQ client on both machines. This type of tracing only works when amqmdnet.dll cannot find its mq buddies in the cache. On a clean machine tracing worked.

Comment: It would be good to write up a answer to your own question to help people that may have the same problem in the future.  Provide specifics of how you diagnosed the problem and the solution that you provided in your comment.

Comment: @JoshMc, thank you. I was wondering what the right way to provide an answer was. I seemed like comment was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tracing described on the support page reference in the question only works if no installation of IBM MQ exists on the machine. We discovered that the machine we thought was clean actually had IBM Websphere 7.5 installed. Once we took it out tracing started working as expected. I assume that tracing must be done through the installed client if it exists on the machine.